# Update Word doc's table of contents part automatically using .NET?

Tags: .net, ms-word, openxml

In Word 2007, you can right-click on a table of contents area and tell it to update its page numbers to point to wherever the current page of that link is. I'd like to do this programmatically, without COM, with the DocumentFormat.OpenXml assemblies. I'm having some troubles Googling it due to the nature of the phrase "table of contents," and can't find much in the namespace to work off of.

Is this possible with those assemblies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this thread on OpenXML Developer:

[How to update Word (.docx) TOC?](https://web.archive.org/web/20101128020104/http://openxmldeveloper.org/forums/permalink/4680/4706/ShowThread.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

We have had a long discussion in [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762684/how-to-generate-table-of-contents-using-openxml-sdk-2-0) regarding generating Table Of Content (TOC) with help of OpneXML SDK 2.0. And there is a solution to achieve that. Look at this thread for details: [How to generate Table Of Contents using OpenXML SDK 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762684/how-to-generate-table-of-contents-using-openxml-sdk-2-0)